# Generating expressions from permutations of variables and operators

Tags: python, regex, string

So, I've decided that it's time to learn regular expressions.  Thus, I set out to solve various problems, and after a bit of smooth sailing, I seem to have hit a wall and need help getting unstuck.

#### The task:

Given a list of characters and logical operators, find all possible combinations of these characters and operators that are not gibberish.

For example, given:

```
my_list = ['p', 'q', '&', '|']
```

the output would be:

```
answers = ['p', 'q', 'p&q', 'p|q'...]
```

However, strings like 'pq&' and 'p&|' are gibberish and therefore not allowed.

Naturally, as more elements are added to my_list, the more complicated the process becomes.

#### My current approach:

(I'd like to learn how to solve it with regex, but I am also curious if there exists a better way, too... but again, my focus is regex)

**step 1:**

find all permutations of the elements such that each permutation is `3 <= x <= len(my_list)` long.

**step 2:**

Loop over the list, and if a regex match is found, pull that element out and put it in the `answers` list.

(I'm not married to this 2-step approach, it is just what seemed most logical to me)

#### My current code, minus the regex:

```
    import re
    from itertool import permutations

    my_list = ['p', 'q', '~r', 'r', '|', '&']
    foo = []
    answers = []
    count = 3
    
    while count < 7:
        for i in permutations(a, count):
            i = ''.join(k for k in i)
            foo.append(i)
        count +=1

    for i in foo:
        if re.match(r'insert_regex', i):
            answers.append(i)
        else:
            None
    print answers
```

Now, I have tried a vast slew of different regex's to get this to work (too many to list them all here) but some of the main ones are:

A straightforward approach by finding all the cases that have two letters side by side, or two operators side by side, then instead of appending 'answers', I just removed them from 'foo'. This is the regex I tried:

```
    r'(\w\w)[&\|]{2,}'
```

and did not even come close.

I then decided to try and find the strings that I wanted, as opposed to the ones I did not want.

First I tested:

```
    r'^[~\w]'
```

to make sure I could get the strings whose first character were a letter or a negation. This worked. I was happy.

I then tried:

```
    r'^[~\w][&\|]'
```

to try and get the next logical operator; however, it only picked up strings whose first character was a letter, and ignored all of the strings whose first character was a negation.

I then tried a conditional so that if the first character was a negation, the next character would be a letter, otherwise it would be an operator:

```
    r'^(?(~)\w|[&\|])'
```

but this thew me "error: bad character in group name".

I then tried to resolve this error by:

```
    r'^(?:(~)\w|[&\|])'
```

But that returned only strings that started with '~' or an operator.

I then tried a slew of other things related to conditionals and groupings (2 days worth, actually), but I can't seem to find a solution. Part of the problem is that I don't know enough about regex to know where to go to find the solution, so I have kind of been wandering around the internet aimlessly.

I have run through a lot of tutorials and explanation pages, but they are all rather opaque and don't piece things together in a way is conducive to understanding... they just sort of throw out code for you to copy and paste or mimic.

Any insights you have would be much appreciated, and as much as I would love an answer to the problem, if possible, an ELI5 explanation of what the solution does would be excellent for my own progress.

Comment: You can train yourself on [RegEx101](https://regex101.com/). There is a Python RegEx evaluator.

Comment: Aren't you trying to match strings that start with a letter(s), then a non-letter/digit + again letters? Try something like `r'^[^\W\d_]+(?:[\W_][^\W\d_]+)*$'`, see [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/yBUd8N/1).

Comment: If the non-word char can only appear once, use [`r'^[^\W\d_]+(?:[\W_][^\W\d_]+)?$'`](https://regex101.com/r/yBUd8N/2). Probably, you just can use a simpler `r'^\w+(?:[&|]\w+)?$'`. A lot depends on what chars you actually can have.

Comment: @WiktorStribizew This still outputs gibberish, such as 'pqr', 'p~r|r&q', etc.

I have all the permutations of the letters and operators in a list.  Some of the elements in this list are valid logic statements (e.g., p&q) but most are not (e.g., pq&). I need to find the valid ones and disregard the invalid ones.

Comment: You should put the solution in an answer, not edit your question. And instead of adding "solved" to the title, mark an answer as "accepted".

Answer (score 1):

In a bitter twist of irony, it turns out that I had the solution written down (I documented all the regex's I tried), but it originally failed because I forgot to remove strings from the original list, not the copy.

If anyone is looking for a solution to the problem, the following code worked on all of my test cases (can't promise beyond that, however).

```
    import re
    from itertools import permutations
    import copy

    a = ['p', 'q', 'r', '~r', '|', '&']
    foo = []
    count = 3

    while count < len(a)+1:
        for j in permutations(a, count):
            j = ''.join(k for k in j)
            foo.append(j)
        count +=1

    foo_copy = copy.copy(foo)

    for i in foo:
        if re.search(r'(^[&\|])|(\w\w)|(\w~)|([&\|][&\|])|([&\|]$)', i):
            foo_copy.remove(i)
        else:
            None

    print foo_copy
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a list of variables (characters), binary operators, and/or variables prefixed with a unitary operator (like `~`). The last case can be dealt with just like a variable.

As binary operators need a variable at either side, we can conclude that a valid expression is an alternation of variables and operators, starting and ending with a variable.

So, you could first divide the input list into two lists based on whether an item is a variable or an operator. Then you could increase the size of the output you will generate, and for each size, get the permutations of both lists and zip these in order to build a valid expression each time. This way you don't need a regular expression to verify the validity.

Here is the suggested function:

```
from itertools import permutations, zip_longest, chain

def expressions(my_list):
    answers = []
    variables = [x for x in my_list if x[-1].isalpha()]
    operators = [x for x in my_list if not x[-1].isalpha()]
    max_var_count = min(len(operators) + 1, len(variables))

    for var_count in range(1, max_var_count+1):
        for vars in permutations(variables, var_count):
            for ops in permutations(operators, var_count-1):
                answers.append(''.join(list(chain.from_iterable(zip_longest(vars, ops)))[:-1]))
    return answers

print(expressions(['p', 'q', '~r', 'r', '|', '&']))
```